# Adding a New Language Locale to Django

Tags: python, django, locale, django-settings

I'm trying to add site translations for a few African languages that Django 1.6.8 does not support. I don't need the admin to to work in those languages, but I do need to support them.

My site already has working translations in 25 languages from languages officially supported by Django and they are divided by subdomain, so de.mysite.com is German. I'm using subdomain middleware to set the locale based on the subdomain, like so:

```
class SubDomainLanguage(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        prefix = None
        try:
            prefix = request.META['HTTP_HOST'].split('.')[0]
            if prefix == 'no':
                prefix = 'nb'
            request.session['django_language'] = prefix
        except KeyError:
            pass
        if not prefix:
            request.session['django_language'] = 'en'
```

Various web searches have led me to a point where it feels like I'm close to adding support for these languages, but visiting yo.mysite.com gives me the English version of the site, so something's missing (de.mysite.com is in German, as intended).

Yoruba translations exist in locale/yo/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo and django.po, and python manage.py compilemessages worked fine.

Here are the related lines from my settings.py file:

```
from django.conf import global_settings
from django.utils.translation import gettext_noop

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'subdomainmiddleware.SubDomainLanguage',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    ...
)

global_settings.LANGUAGES += ('ak', gettext_noop('Akan'))
global_settings.LANGUAGES += ('ig', gettext_noop('Igbo'))
global_settings.LANGUAGES += ('rw', gettext_noop('Rwanda'))
global_settings.LANGUAGES += ('sn', gettext_noop('Shona'))
global_settings.LANGUAGES += ('yo', gettext_noop('Yoruba'))
global_settings.LANGUAGES += ('zu', gettext_noop('Zulu'))

EXTRA_LANG_INFO = {
    'ak': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'ak',
        'name': 'Akan',
        'name_local': u'Akan'
    },
    'ig': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'ig',
        'name': 'Igbo',
        'name_local': u'Asụsụ Igbo'
    },
    'rw': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'rw',
        'name': 'Rwanda',
        'name_local': u'Kinyarwanda'
    },
    'sn': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'sn',
        'name': 'Shona',
        'name_local': u'chiShona'
    },
    'yo': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'yo',
        'name': 'Yoruba',
        'name_local': u'èdè Yorùbá'
    },
    'zu': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'zu',
        'name': 'Zulu',
        'name_local': u'isiZulu'
    },
}

import django.conf.locale

LANG_INFO = dict(django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO.items() + EXTRA_LANG_INFO.items())
django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO = LANG_INFO
```

What could be missing? Or is there maybe something in the wrong order?